# Checking Equal Pointers & Memory Roundup

Tags: c, pointers, struct

So, I'm implementing queue using struct and pointers in C:

Note: I'm using max_cells = 3 for my program.

Here is my queue.h:

```
struct queue {
int max_cells; // Maximum number of cells in the queue
int cells_used; // Number of cells used
void **head; // Pointer to the head of queue
void **tail; // Pointer to the tail of queue
void **queue_base; // Pointer to the base of the queue
};

typedef struct queue Queue; // For convenience
```

And here is my code for enqueue:

```
/**
  * Enqueue a pointer into the queue
  * @param which_queue Pointer to Queue you want to push onto
  * @param ptr Pointer to be pushed
  * @return 1 if successful, 0 if not
  */
  int enqueue(Queue *which_queue, void *ptr) {

  // If the Queue is already full, print a message and terminate the function
  if ((which_queue->cells_used) == (which_queue->max_cells)) {
  printf("The queue is full. It can only contains %d cells.\n", which_queue->max_cells);
  return 0;
  }

  // Otherwise, enqueue the cell that head points to
  // Checking tail++ to see if it goes off the queue
  // If it does, then make tail point to the queue_base
  if (((which_queue->tail)++) == ((which_queue->queue_base) + (which_queue->max_cells))) {
  which_queue->tail = which_queue->queue_base;
  } else {
    // Push the pointer to the queue
    *(which_queue->tail) = ptr;
    // Point to the next free cell
    (which_queue->tail)++;
    // Then, increase the number of cells used in the Queue
    (which_queue->cells_used)++;
  }
  return 1; // Indicate success
  }
```

I check my program by printing out the memory location that each one points to: (Foo are just random structs)

```
Enqueued new_foo1.
Current number of cells in the queue: 1
Head pointer is pointing to: 0x147d040
Tail pointer is pointing to: 0x147d050
Base pointer is pointing to: 0x147d040
Enqueued new_foo2.
Current number of cells in the queue: 2
Head pointer is pointing to: 0x147d040
Tail pointer is pointing to: 0x147d060
Enqueued new_foo3.
Current number of cells in the queue: 3
Head pointer is pointing to: 0x147d040
Tail pointer is pointing to: 0x147d070
The queue is full. It can only contains 3 cells.
-----------------------
Dequeued new_foo1
Current number of cells in the queue: 2
Head pointer is pointing to: 0x147d050
Tail pointer is pointing to: 0x147d070
Enqueued new_foo4
Current number of cells in the queue: 3
Head pointer is pointing to: 0x147d050
Tail pointer is pointing to: 0x147d080
*** (which_queue->queue_base) + (which_queue->max_cells) = 0x147d058 
Dequeued new_foo2
Current number of cells in the queue: 2
Head pointer is pointing to: 0x147d060
Tail pointer is pointing to: 0x147d080
Dequeued new_foo3
Current number of cells in the queue: 1
Head pointer is pointing to: 0x147d070
Tail pointer is pointing to: 0x147d080
```

The problem lies in the line marked with ***. Why does this happen? I think the memory location should be 0x147d070.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Why should it be `0x147d070`? and what if it's not?

Comment: I'm trying to make a wraparound queue. So, when I dequeue new_foo1, the base of the queue should be empty. And I want to move the tail pointer to where the base is. So, I have to make sure that the function understands that if I increment the tail pointer, it's going off the queue.

Comment: you increment tail twice in your code per enqueue, once in the if-condition, and once in the else, and when the if-condition is true `ptr` is never added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to be more explicit about exactly what the tail pointer does -- does it point to the last entry added to the queue, or does it point to the free space after the last entry added to the queue? Some people like to do it one way, and some like to do it the other.

Since you are incrementing the tail pointer first, this implies that you want the tail pointer to point to the last entry added. But as rpattiso already pointed out, then you should not also increment the pointer after using it to store the entry into the queue.

One other thing -- If you use the tail pointer this way, be sure that when you add something to an empty queue that the head pointer is set properly.